# How do I change the Airline theme?

Tags: vimrc, plugin-airline

I'm using airline with its default theme (relying from my theme gruvbox).

I use `:AirlineTheme base16` while I have already opened my vim to change my airline theme to base16.

But I want to change the default airline theme permanently, when I set

```
AirlineTheme base16
call AirlineTheme base16
set AirlineTheme base16
```

- `AirlineTheme base16` -- Gives no failure message but removes all airline themes.
- `call AirlineTheme base16` -- Gives error `"Missing parentheses`. I also tried it as `call AirlineTheme base16()`. Still same error.
- `set AirlineTheme base16` -- This says `unknown option AirlineTheme`

How can I set it?

Comment: "It fails" is not a very detailed problem description... The second and third for (`call ...AirlineTheme` and `set AirlineTheme`) are invalid, so what error do you get when you try the first one?

Comment: Have you installed the base16 theme? See [this FAQ entry](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline/wiki/FAQ#the-themes-are-missing).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put the following in your .vimrc:

```
let g:airline_theme='base16'
```

You'll also need to install the [vim-airline/vim-airline-themes](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline-themes) plugin.

Comment: Just an FYI: [What you think you get with ``` is not necessarily what you get.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125148/270345)

Comment: Functionally, what was the difference between the two format-stylings used here? For a one liner, the difference is minimal

Comment: Functionally, right now, no difference. If we ever get syntax highlighting for Vim, it would make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think now you can just do

`:AirlineTheme base16`

to temporarily set the theme.

Make sure to have Airline and AirlineThemes installed

Comment: Welcome to vi.stackexchange. This was already mentioned in the question.